# Excel find text value in string

Tags: excel, formula

I have a string such as K68272CAA6A1
And need to do that, formula will pass the first character (I mean string will be 68272CAA6A1 in mind) and formula will find the first **text** character. And cell value will be 7. Because first text character is "C" and it's the 7th character of my string (include "K" character).

And after that I'll split rest of them. But I'm confused about this issue.

Comment: Can you add an example code of what you're trying to do? I think in this case even pseudo code would be great.

Comment: If we use this case; K68272CAA6A1. It has to be K68272 CAA6A1 finally. I mean I have to cut the string before first text character. (Formula has to pass first text character, I mean "K" character) @methode

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, a formula that implements this functionality (assuming cell `A1 = K68272CAA6A1` and `B1 = K`) would be:

`=FIND(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(B1,A1)),"1",""),"2",""),"3",""),"4",""),"5",""),"6",""),"7",""),"8",""),"9",""),1),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(B1,A1)))-1`

The long sequence of substitute is there to remove the numbers (I couldn't find a specific formula to remove them).

This gigantic formula for your example would simply give the answer `6`.

To get the strings separated as you want all you need to do is `=LEFT(A1,D1)` supposing the long formula is on `D1` and `=RIGHT(A1,D1)`, which in your example would yield respectively `K68272` and `CAA6A1`

Comment: Your final paragraph seems to assume that the two chunks have the same length. Probably a terrible assumption since if that were the case we wouldn't need this letter-based criteria..

Comment: No it doesn't, and in no way my paragraphs says that! 

`LEFT` takes what is to the left from an index, and `RIGHT` picks what is right from the intex. The only way this formula would spĺit it into half is if `D1` was equal to half the length of `A1`!

Comment: The second parameter of the `RIGHT` function is a length NOT an index.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for the position of the 2nd letter in your string.  That number is given by the following **array-entered** formula.

To enter an array formula, hold down `ctrl+shift` while hitting `Enter`.  If you do this correctly, in the Formula Bar you will see braces `{...}` around the formula:

```
=MATCH(FALSE,ISNUMBER(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("2:99")),1)/1),0)+1
```

The `99` just needs to be some number larger than the length of your longest string.